# How do I make a back button with Drupal form API?

Tags: forms, api, drupal, button, onclick

I need to do this but with Drupal forms:

```
<input type="button" class="button-user" value="Back" onclick="location.href='edit'"/>
```

I tried doing this but it did not work:

```
$form['back']['#prefix'] = "<input type='button' class='button-user' value='Back' onclick='location.href='edit''/>;
```

and also:

```
$form['back'] = array(
  '#type' => 'button',
  '#value' => 'Back',
  '#attributes' => array(
     'class' => 'button-user',
     'onclick' => 'location.href=edit',        
   )       
 );
```

Comment: you never close the first one with quotation marks `"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$form['back']['#markup'] = "<input type='button' class='button-user' value='Back' onclick='location.href=\'edit\''/>";
```

Comment: see my answer using Drupal Form API

Answer (score 3):

```
$form['back']['#markup'] = "<input type='button' class='button-user' value='Back' onclick='window.history.go(-1)'/>";
```

This works for any page.

Answer (score 2):

Just adding my version, which seems to work great in 7, just catch it in the rebuild cycle and redirect instead. Extensible, can add any other buttons to do things, note the spelling of value "Back" is the name of the "op" (operation).. something that confused and annoyed me until I figured it out.

```
function mymodule_something_form($form,&$form_state){

    //... Rest of form

    $form['unused_form_id_back'] = array(
        '#type' => 'button',
        '#value' => 'Back',
    );
    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => 'Do Stuff!'
    );
    return $form;
}

function mymodule_something_form_validate($form, &$form_state)
{
    if($form_state['values']['op'] == 'Back'){
        drupal_goto('something/that_page');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing up the "op" issue.  That bugged me too.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest option in Drupal Form API, Using **#attributes** option.

```
$form['back-btn'] = array(
    '#type'                 => 'button',
    '#value'                => t('Back'),
    '#attributes'           => array('onclick' => onclick='window.history.back();'),
);
```

Comment: My question was originally for drupal 6 4 years ago but i think it might be useful to others, thanks you.

Comment: $form['back-btn'] = array(
                 '#type' => 'button',
       '#value' => t('Back'),
                 '#attributes' => array('onclick' => 'window.history.back();'),
                );

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be this one:

```
function YOUR_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch($form_id) {
    case "YOUR_FORM_ID":

      unset($form['#validate']); //Maybe necessary

      $form['actions']['back'] = array(
        "#type" => "button",
        "#value" => t('Back'),
        "#weight" => 15,
        "#executes_submit_callback" => FALSE,
        '#limit_validation_errors' => array(),
        '#ajax' => array(
          'callback' => 'YOUR_MODULE_go_back_callback'
        )
      );

      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}

function YOUR_MODULE_go_back_callback() {
  $html = '
  <script type"text/javascript">
  window.history.go(-1);
  </script>
  ';
  return $html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I preferred a solution that required no JavaScript. Similar to the answer by  Grizly, but without putting it in the form validation, which felt ugly. But the code below offers a link button.

```
function my_form(&$form, &$form_state) {
  // Some form elements

  // Regular submit button
  $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit'),
  );

  // Back button (different submit handler prevent the standard submit and takes us
  // to the redirect-submit).
  $form['actions']['back'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Go back'),
    '#submit' => array('custom_back_button'),
  );
}

// Custom form callback for redirection.
function custom_back_button($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['redirect'] = '/edit';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the back button I m using.
The "return false" avoid the form submission.

```
 $form['back'] = array(
  '#type' => 'button',
  '#value' => t('<< Back'),
  '#attributes' => array(
    'onclick' => 'window.history.back();return false;',
  ),
);
```